# How to break for loop in JSrender

Tags: jquery, jsrender

for example

```
"data" : [{
                            "name" : "peter"
                        }, {
                            "name" : "John"
                        }
                    ]

{{for data}}

{{if name == "peter"}}
{{:name}} 

{{/if}}

{{/for}}
```

here i need to break for loop when name is peter. i dont want next iterate

Answer (score 0):

According to the developers, [this seems to be unsupported](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/184).
The best option would be to deliver the collection already filtered.

Comment: you mean break concept is not implemented in jsrender.?

Comment: Precisely. According to the developers, "this would make the implementation very procedural and stateful". Many developers like to avoid stateful code as much as possible, since it's more prone to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

As Haroldo_OK says, there is no supported feature for declaratively breaking the loop (such as a `{{break/}}` tag). But you can write a helper function such as  `truncate`, which takes the `data` array and returns an appropriately truncated array, and then write:

```
{{for ~truncate(data)}...{{/for}}
```

or

```
{{for data convert=~truncate}}...{{/for}}
```

Or you can write a custom tag based on `{{for}}` and provde a break or a truncate feature. See the `{{range}}` tag samples: http://www.jsviews.com/#search?s=%7B%7Brange&f=jsv-txt-